# libtool: error: can't build x86_64-w64-mingw32 shared library unless -no-undefined is specified

Tags: makefile, c++17, mingw, msys, openfst

I am trying to build and install the [OpenFst](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/DistInstall) library on windows10 using MINGW64 with Msys but i got the following error during the building with make. I first used this command:

```
 ./configure --enable-grm --enable-far --enable-ngram-fsts MAKE="mingw32-make"
```

some of the checking results from this command  generates no:

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... ./configure: line 7016: cmp: command not found
./configure: line 7016: cmp: command not found
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for unistd.h... no
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... ./configure: line 8930: diff: command `not found`
checking whether to build static libraries... no
```

The other checking results are ok and yes. Then I used the make command:

```
mingw32-make
```

it works for some files then terminated by that error:

```
libtool:   error: can't build x86_64-w64-mingw32 shared library unless -no-undefined is 
specified
```

It is my first time to build with MinGW. So, I do not know what the error means and if the resulting "no" checking from the configuration responsible for it.

Comment: Does `diff` command work? You might need to install it. Also, you should be using `make` instead of `mingw32-make`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, diff not working. and also make not working but "mingw32-make" make the same job. what is the difference between them?

Comment: `make` is a full-fledged Make (uses MSYS2's Cygwin fork). `mingw32-make` is an attempt to port Make to Windows without Cygwin, it uses `cmd` instead of `sh` as the shell, and since most makefiles don't expect it, not all of them work with it. Last time I tried it, it was also fairly buggy.

Comment: *"diff not working. and also make not working"* You need to install both.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I installed both of them and used make instead of `mingw32-make` but  the error still appears.

Comment: `cmp` also seems to be missing. Are there any other errors when running `./configure`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no, no errors issued during the `./configure`

Comment: To confirm, it doesn't say "not found" about any other commands? What happens if you re-run `./configure` after installing `cmp`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal.

MinGW does not allow building shared libraries (DLLs) when there are still unresolved symbols, because on Windows each symbol referenced from a DLL must point to something that exists. On other platforms this is not always required.

So you should pass to `-Wl,-no-undefined` to `gcc` when linking.

For projects using autoconf's `configure` this is normally already done if it was a recent enough version of autoconf. Otherwise you may need to add `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-no-undefined"` to the `configure` line.
If that doesn't help you can try to change it in the `libtool` file generated by `configure`.

So specicially you can try this in MSYS/MSYS2 shell:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-Wl,-no-undefined"
```

and if that doesn't work you can also try this (after the `configure` command and before running `make`):

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/\(allow_undefined=\)yes/\1no/" libtool
```

Other build tools like cmake, meson or scons already know how to build Windows DLLs and need no special treatment.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it

Comment: I ran into the same issue, also with OpenFST, and only `sed` worked. `-Wl,-no-undefined` is passed to the linker, but has no effect.